# Cannot read .bbl file when using the .bst file

Tags: bibliographies

I'm writing a paper using the .bst file (theapa.bst) which is indicated by a journal publication.

Here is a simple example (main.tex) to reproduce a problem that I'm facing:

```
\documentclass[twoside,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{jair, theapa, rawfonts}

\usepackage{natbib}

\jairheading{1}{1993}{1-15}{6/91}{9/91}
\ShortHeadings{Test}
{}
\firstpageno{1}

\begin{document}
    
    \title{Test}
    
    \author{}
    
    \maketitle

\begin{abstract}
Paper~\cite{Zhang18}
\end{abstract}

\vskip 0.2in
\bibliography{matching}
\bibliographystyle{theapa}

\end{document}
```

The following are .bib file (matching.bib):

```
@inproceedings{Zhang18,
    author    = {Yuzhe Zhang and Kentaro Yahiro and Toshiya Sato},
    title     = {Strategyproof and Fair Matching Mechanism for Union of Symmetric {M}-convex
    Constraints},
    booktitle = {Proceedings of the 27th International Joint Conference on
    Artificial Intelligence (IJCAI-18)},
    pages     = {590--596},
    year      = {2018},
}
```

Then error occurs like:

```
main.bbl line 4
Undefined control sequence. et~al.}{2018}]{Zhang18}
```

The log file is:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2020.5.17)  7 NOV 2020 14:33
entering extended mode
 restricted \write18 enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**main.tex
(./main.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2020-05-14>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size11.clo
File: size11.clo 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count167
\c@section=\count168
\c@subsection=\count169
\c@subsubsection=\count170
\c@paragraph=\count171
\c@subparagraph=\count172
\c@figure=\count173
\c@table=\count174
\abovecaptionskip=\skip47
\belowcaptionskip=\skip48
\bibindent=\dimen134
) (./jair.sty
Document Style `jair' -- May 1993.
\aftertitskip=\skip49
\beforetitskip=\skip50
\interauthorskip=\skip51
\aftermaketitskip=\skip52
) (./theapa.sty
Package: theapa 1997/06/03 Version 3.0 APA Citation Style
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 122.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \nocite on input line 417.
\bibleftmargin=\skip53
\bibparsep=\skip54
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/rawfonts.sty
Package: rawfonts 1994/05/08 Low-level LaTeX 2.09 font compatibility

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/somedefs.sty
Package: somedefs 1994/06/01 v0.03 Toolkit for optional definitions
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for U+lasy on input line 49
.

(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ulasy.fd
File: ulasy.fd 1998/08/17 v2.2e LaTeX symbol font definitions
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/natbib/natbib.sty
Package: natbib 2010/09/13 8.31b (PWD, AO)
\bibhang=\skip55
\bibsep=\skip56
LaTeX Info: Redefining \cite on input line 694.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \citeauthor on input line 712.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \citeyear on input line 735.
\c@NAT@ctr=\count175
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdfmode.def
File: l3backend-pdfmode.def 2020-05-05 L3 backend support: PDF mode
\l__kernel_color_stack_int=\count176
\l__pdf_internal_box=\box45
)
(./main.aux)
\openout1 = `main.aux'.

LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OML/cmm/m/it on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMS/cmsy/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OT1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for T1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for TS1/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for OMX/cmex/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    Checking defaults for U/cmr/m/n on input line 11.
LaTeX Font Info:    ... okay on input line 11.


Package natbib Warning: Citation `Zhang18' on page 1 undefined on input line 20
.

(./main.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
\NAT@tmp ->\protect \BCAY 
                          {Zhang, Yahiro,\ \BBA \ Sato}{Zhang et~al.}{2018}
l.4   et~al.}{2018}]{Zhang18}
                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> ...ter \NAT@ifcmd \NAT@tmp (@)(@)\@nil 
                                                  {Zhang18}
l.4   et~al.}{2018}]{Zhang18}
                             
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.

)

Package natbib Warning: There were undefined citations.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

]
(./main.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 1010 strings out of 480480
 13548 string characters out of 5899675
 248169 words of memory out of 5000000
 17058 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 548022 words of font info for 83 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1141 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 23i,5n,25p,218b,165s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-s
uper-ts1.enc}</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/c
mr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmr
8.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cmti10
.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm0800.p
fb>
Output written on main.pdf (1 page, 66903 bytes).
PDF statistics:
 33 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 23 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 1 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

In addition, when I cite the following article,

```
@article{gibbard:1973,
    title={Manipulation of Voting Schemes: A General Result},
    author={Gibbard Allan},
    journal={Journal of the Econometric Society},
    pages={587--601},
    year={1973},
    publisher={JSTOR},
}
```

the error has appeared.

```
You can't pop an empty literal stack for entry gibbard:1973
while executing---line 2867 of file theapa.bst
(There was 1 error message)
```

Why does it happen?

Comment: Unfortunately, the error message shown in the question seems to be cut off or seems to be a simplified/condensed version of the actual message from TeX. Can you please copy the full error message directly from the `.log` file. It would also help if you could post the contents of the `.bbl` file here.

Comment: Generally APA based bibliography styles are not compatible with `natbib`. Removing `natbib` avoids the error.

Comment: Thanks moewe. I added the content of .log file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the clue, Guido. I'd like to use \citep or \citet in the paper. How can I avoid an error without natbib?

Comment: `\citet` should correspond to `\citeA` and `\citep` to `\cite`

Comment: It works well, thanks a lot! Another problem has appeared. I'd be glad if you also give me solutions.

Comment: If you're lucky the problem is just the missing `volume` field in `gibbard:1973`.

Comment: Yes, works normally! Thank you very much! I didn't know that @article must need volume field.